# Print a 2-column report in .net

Tags: .net, crystal-reports, reportviewer

How do you create a report with 2 columns:

Example:

```
Student Name:   Reyes JA               Student Name:   Reyes K 
Student ID:     2008-1000              Student ID:     2008-1000
Semester:       First Sem, 2008-2009   Semester:       First Sem, 2008-2009
Amount:         2000.00                Amount:         2000.00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution by using the ReportViewer.

You can set the number of column property. The reportviewer will automatically create the 2-column report when the report is shown with data.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't used Crystal in ages... but that looks like a "label" report to me (aka "format with multiple columns").